# Jquery change text color if

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change text color on class status

When text is number bigger than 0 i use this code and works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".status").filter(function () {
    return $(this).html() > 0;
  }).parent().css('color', 'red');
});
```

How I can make blue text when the text is *error*? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
return $(this).html() == "error";
```

Comment: Try `return $(this).text() == "error";` if you mean that the text will be error.

Comment: If it don't work, what do it do?

Comment: No, what?......

Comment: @Zorken17 i tried but dont work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should do it:

You need to get the `.text()` from `.status` the you need to `.trim()` it so it dose not contain spaces. Than you can compare error with error.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".status").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().trim() == "error";
  }).parent().css('color', 'blue');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Parent
  <div class="status">
    error
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery API [isNumeric](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) to validate if input is a number

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".status")
    .filter(function () {
    return $.isNumeric($(this).val());
})
.parent().css('color', 'blue');});
```

Comment: I have 3 solutions - when number, -number and text error... I want to change color when text is "error"

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".status").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === "error";
  }).parent().css('color', 'blue');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will not work because the string from `$(this).text()` is not equal to error. Try doing `console.log($(this).text() === "error")` and you will get false.